# "SSLHandshakeException: Error signing certificate verify" after certificate update

Tags: java, ssl, mtls

I have a SpringBoot 2 application, running in Tomcat 8.5 with Java8 Runtime.
It is is using a JKS Keystore for two different certs/keys which are both used by the application for mutual TLS (mTLS).

Since we retrieved a new version of the certificate from the CA admin, the application cannot use the keystore anymore with the following exception, as soon as a client mTLS call is attempted.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Error signing certificate verify
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1174)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:369)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
    at UrlEngine.submit(UrlEngine.java:52)
    at JCurl.execute(JCurl.java:126)
    at JCurl.main(JCurl.java:62)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.chooseProvider(Signature.java:1138)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign(Signature.java:1188)
    at java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:553)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateVerify.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:1591)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1171)
    ... 13 more
```

We have rebuilt the Keystore multiple times from its PKCS12 origin and when using the exported cert and key with e.g. curl everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

We finally found the solution to the issue. It was caused by the alias set in the JKS keystore. The operations use a script to generate the JKS keystore from PKCS12, while doing that friendly names/ aliases are set to the JKS keystore. The alias which was autogenerated by the script and set in the JKS file was too long or contained invalid characters. Thus we fixed it by setting the alias to a very short name which only contained hyphens and alphanumeric characters.

Thus you can fix the issue, if you run into the same one using this command:

```
keytool -changealias -alias "previous-long-alias" -destalias "new-short-alias" -keystore /path/to/keystore.jks
```

Use the `-keypass` and `-storepass` arguments, if needed.

Comment: One more thing that might help here is this post: http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/JDK-8180819-No-installed-provider-supports-this-key-sun-security-pkcs-PKCS8Key-td318693.html